# Disable DEBUG level logs in logback.xml keeping INFO and ERROR level logs

Tags: spring, log4j, logback, slf4j, disable

My logback.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <jmxConfigurator/>
  <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener"/>

  <property name="LOG_DIR" value="/tmp/logs"/>
  <springProperty name="appName" source="spring.application.name"/>
  <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender" name="STDOUT">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <Pattern>
        some pattern
      </Pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <logger additivity="false" level="DEBUG"
    name="xyz">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </logger>
  <root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

I am trying to disable DEBUG logs from the entire application and couldn't find a way to do so. I want to print INFO, ERROR level logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either leave the only root logger with *INFO* level. This means it would log only *INFO*, *WARN* and *ERROR*. However it seems that *WARN* is not something you would like to log.

**Or** you can use [filters](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html) like **LevelFilter**. Below is the example from the documentation you can find by the provided link.

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
      <level>INFO</level>
      <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
      <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>
        %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{30} - %msg%n
      </pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```