# Is there a way to disable slf4j logger's debug messages?

Tags: java, slf4j

I have a application using various external libraries, which mostly use slf4j as default logger. Inside my IDE I don't see any Debug-Logs in the console, how ever, when building my project it is spammed with them. I really don't need the debug messages of other people, so I'm trying to find a way to disabled them completly.

Here is my default logback.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %boldCyan(%-34.-34thread) %red(%10.10X{jda.shard}) %boldGreen(%-15.-15logger{0}) %highlight(%-6level) %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
    <root level="debug">
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: check solutions from here - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58738476/disable-debug-level-logs-in-logback-xml-keeping-info-and-error-level-logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58738476/disable-debug-level-logs-in-logback-xml-keeping-info-and-error-level-logs)

Answer (score 2):

Remove below part from your code:

```xml
<root level="debug">
    </root>
```

Below picture shows which level contains other levels.

[image]